# In JSF2 do I have to define all methods when backing bean implements a custom interface

Tags: jsf-2

looking for help and advice here. My environment is JSF2.

I have a number of forms that all have the need to upload a file. I want to use a common modal popup dialog to handle the file upload.

Each form has a different backing bean and I want them to all implement the methods required to support the file upload operations.

I have written the following interface to define the methods that each bean must implement to support this file upload

```
public interface ComponentUploader
{

void uploadComponentClicked(ActionEvent e);

void handleFileUpload(FileUploadEvent event);

List<UploadedFile> getUploadedFiles();

void saveUploadComponentClicked();
}
```

The backing bean classes then implement this Interface...

```
public class SupplierBean  implements ComponentUploader
{
    public void handleFileUpload(FileUploadEvent event) {  
    ...
    } 
    public void uploadComponentClicked(ActionEvent e)
    {
    ...
    }
    public void saveUploadComponentClicked()
    {
    ...
    }
    public List<UploadedFile> getUploadedFiles()
    {
    ...
    }

    //other public methods...
    public void initialise()
    {
    ...
    }
```

Now, each backing bean has other public methods such as initialise(), however these methods are not required to implement the ComponentUploader interface.

Whilst the above compiles correctly, when deployed (in JBOSS AS 7) when I try to call the initialise method from an actionListener on my web page, I get Method Not Found errors;

```
Caused by: javax.el.MethodNotFoundException: Method not found: Proxy for view class: com.vesey.searchpoint.interfaces.ComponentUploader of EJB: SupplierBean.initialise()
```

I do not understand why I am not able to call a public method on a backing bean if it is not defined in the interface. Is it because the interface is being interpreted by JSF as the definition of it's business interface?

What the the correct approach here? I want to have several beans that all support the ComponentUploader interface, but each have their own callable public methods too. Should I be looking at abstract classes instead of interfaces.

Thanks
Rich

Comment: Is it a JSF managed bean or an EJB? The exception suggests that it's an EJB.

Comment: Perhaps related to JSF EJB's and actionListeners: http://www.seamframework.org/136633.lace

Answer (score 0):

I think you got the wrong signature for the actionListener, the problem has nothing to do with interfaces.
You need some method signature like:

```
public void initialise(ActionEvent event)
```

Maybe you have some config for the bean that is not shown in your code sample ?